# general URL format

Tags: java, regex, url, netbeans-8

I'm trying to solve this problem that extract URL from a big text and i been looking for general format for URL until I found this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL; and I make this code but I don't know why it didn't found the URL:

```
 Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(http|https|ftp|mailto|file|data|irc|rtsp)(\\:)(^\\w{1})([a-zA-Z0-9/%+.-]*$)\\.(com|net|org|jo)\\/(.+)" , Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
       if(m.matches())
             System.out.println(text) ;
       else
             System.out.println("no matches");
```

Comment: Which URL is not found? Give a concrete example.

Comment: take this text : "i'm trying to solve this problem that extract URL from a big text and i been looking for general format for URL until i found this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL; and i make this code but i don't know why it didn't found the URL :"

Comment: to extract the wkipedia URL

Comment: to extract the wkipedia URL

Comment: What is your $ for?

Comment: @user8545027 you only want the URL part of the url?

Comment: I want the URL part from the whole text in the second comment

Comment: The $ for the end of the line anchor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me this Regex worked:

```
(http|https|ftp|mailto|file|data|irc|rtsp)(\:)(\/\/)([a-zA-Z0-9\/%+.-\/]*)\.(com|net|org|jo)\/(\w*\/)*(\w+)
```

You will have to capture the last group if you want the last part of the URL here that would be group 7

I hope it helped

Comment: this is the answer i been looking for "(http|https|rtps|rtp)://[-A-Za-z0-9+&@#/%?=~_()|!:,.;]*[-A-Za-z0-9+&@#/%=~_()|]"